# Adding CSS File to ejs tempelate using variable from server side

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to add css file dynamically in ejs tempelate.

I know how to include ejs file but not getting how to add css file dynamically.

Code  :-

Index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('template', { title: 'abc',page:'index',cssa:'home'});
});
```

template.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <!-- Here I want to add home.css file -->
  </head>
  <body>
   <!-- including my ejs file -->
   <%- include(page) %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/\<%= cssa %>\" >
<% include %><%= cssa %><% .css %>
```

Goal:

to pass the server side received variable(cssa) in stylesheet source.

Comment: <% var css_link = '/stylesheets/' + cssa + '.css'; %>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= css_link %>" >

Comment: @SpiRT , thanks for help, It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method to include :

```
<% var css_link = '/stylesheets/' + cssa + '.css'; %>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= css_link %>" >
```

Credit goes to  @SpiRT

Alternatively :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/<%=cssa%>.css">`

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to concat the css path and variable, you can also do it as follows:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/<%= yourVariableName %>.css' />
```

Comment: this will work but will always give error on server console that yourVariavleName is not defined.

Comment: It will not give error as you will send this variable from server side. In your case it is cssa.

Comment: `ReferenceError: /root/Documents/dweb/views/template.ejs:11

    9|   <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    10|   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css">

 >> 11|   <% var css_link = '/stylesheets/' + cssa + '.css'; %>

    12|  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= css_link %>" > 

    13|   

    14| </head>

cssa is not defined
`
server side script :
 `res.render('template', { title: 'DUCS',page:'index',opti:opt,cssa:'index'});`

Comment: this is not giving error on client side whenever I am rendering the document but on server side , on each call this error shows in console.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it most convenient to inject custom css scripts through an array which can then be processed in the ejs template.

This method would allow you to render any amount of CSS files that are additionally required  (example, you have a site that uses 1 standard css across all pages but have 1 or 2 page specific ones which can then be included in the model passed through the ejs renderer to that specific page/route). 
In the example it's a given that the css files are in the same folder, however that can be changed to each one's liking:

router side:

```
router.get( ... {
    model = {};
    model.Stylesheets = [];
    model.Stylesheets.push("stylefile");
    res.render("view",{model:model});
});
```

with the custom stylesheets being pushed though to the view, then the ejs files can be something like:

```
<% 
    var customStylesheets = "";

    model.Stylesheets.forEach(function(style){
        customStylesheets+='<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/'+style+'.css">';
    })

%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title><%= model.title %></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/standard.css">
    <%- customStylesheets %>
...
</head>
```

Comment: Yes, we can write this when we are injecting css files as you are creating a string which is looping through all items in object passed from server.

Comment: Yes that's what the code does, it being an array also makes is easier to sort out when multiple css are required, while your solution can only add a single sheet